# cd ${DIR_PATH} returns 'No such file or directory'

Tags: environment-variables, cd-command

OS = `MacOS 10.8.5`/`Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0`.

In my `.bash_profile` I have:

```
export DIR_PATH=~/concrete/path
```

At the terminal

```
>echo ${DIR_PATH}
~/concrete/path
```

Also explicit cd works:

```
>cd ~/concrete/path
>pwd
/Users/myuserid/concrete/path
```

But when I do

```
>cd ${DIR_PATH}
-bash: cd: ~/concrete/path: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem?

Comment: That's odd; it works for me on Linux with bash 3.2.25 and 4.2.37. What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` print?

Comment: 3.2.48(1)-release

Comment: Copy-the following as a single line and paste it to your shell prompt: `export DIR_PATH=~/concrete/path ; echo DIR_PATH=${DIR_PATH} ; cd ${DIR_PATH} ; pwd`

Comment: Is the path literally `~/concrete/path`, or could there be spaces or other special characters in the directory path?

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can you answer the question in my previous comment?

Comment: no sir, none...'

Comment: So what happens when you copy-and-paste the command in my previous comment? (My point is that I can't think of any reason why the `~` shouldn't have worked.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of giving the ~ as your home in .bash_profile give the absolute path:

```
export DIR_PATH=/Users/myuserid/concrete/path
```

The problem is that your bash couldn't substitute `~` to your home dir in your bash profile.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. As far as I know, bash *will* replace `~` by your home directory path, whether it's in `.bash_profile` or not. I can imagine the expansion not working immediately after an `=`, but experiment with bash 3.2.25 and 4.2.37 indicates that that *does* work. What happens when you use `$HOME` rather than `~`? If that works, it would be a better solution.

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually i tested in my bash and for me it worked. So i guess maybe he is using an older version of bash or something like that!

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to using a tilde `~` or using the hard path `/Users/myuserid/...` I'd suggest using the environment variable `$HOME` instead. Variables such as this are typically setup by `login` (see `man login`) in most Unixes, and I would suspect that OSX would do this as well.

*excerpt*

> This should allow the system adminitrator to login even in case of network problems.   The  value  for  `$HOME`, `$USER`, `$SHELL`, `$PATH`, `$LOGNAME`, and `$MAIL` are set according to the appropriate fields in the password entry.  `$PATH` defaults to `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` for normal users, and to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` for root if not other configured.
>
> As always you can use the command `env` to see what variables you have at your disposal too.

#### References

- [Configuring Your OS X Unix Environment](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31442&seqNum=3)

Comment: @KeithThompson - done

Comment: typically the program that logs a user into the system sets that variable, like `login`(1), not the shell.

Comment: @llua - thanks fixed that. I completely forgot about `login`.